# Resolving package conflicts in Python 2.7 Environment

Tags: python, python-2.7, conda, geopandas, virtual-environment

My goal is to run a python script from about 2 years ago.

If someone could point me in the direction of an answer or issue that will help me work through the conflicts between packages to create a working environment for this old script it would be hugely appreciated.

It is written in python 2.

Dependencies are

```
psycopg2
```

and an internal module that imports

```
pandas 
geopandas 
psycopg2-binary
sqlalchemy
pyyaml
scikit-image
beautifultable
tqdm
statistics
rasterio ; sys_platform=="linux2"
geopandas ; sys_platform=="linux2"
\__Python wheels\pyproj-1.9.6-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl ; sys_platform=="win32"
\__Python wheels\GDAL-2.2.4-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl ; sys_platform=="win32"
\__Python wheels\Shapely-1.6.4.post2-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl ; sys_platform=="win32"
\__Python wheels\Fiona-1.8.13-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl ; sys_platform=="win32"
\__Python wheels\rasterio-1.1.2-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl ; sys_platform=="win32"
\__Python wheels\Rtree-0.9.3-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl ; sys_platform=="win32"
geopandas ; sys_platform=="win32"
osmnx==0.9
psycopg2
psycopg2
sqlalchemy 
numpy 
shapely
binascii 
string
```

I can create a python 2.7 environment in conda easily.

When I try to install `geopandas 0.4.0` in that environment conda returns a list of incompatible specifications for example:

```
Package six conflicts for:
geopandas=0.4.0 -> six
geopandas=0.4.0 -> fiona -> six[version='>=1.7']
```

If I try to install the current `geopandas 0.7.0` I get a similar list of conflicts.

Comment: Have you considered using 2to3 to convert the script first? https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html

Comment: I have,  the internal module that is imported is also written in python 2. Porting that is underway but it is not yet usable.

Comment: Which internal module?

Comment: just something we built in house to handle a bunch of different geoprocessing tasks. Internal as in "not public"

Comment: I understand that part. But python3 has been available for close to a decade. 2 years ago, you could've written it not using Python2... So upgrading it is ultimately your best option right now

Comment: you're preaching to the choir, believe me

Comment: I'm guessing this project didn't have a requirements.txt?

Comment: no, but I do wonder whether manually putting one together is my only/best route for getting a working environment built

Comment: Unless you have a version of the program running you're only option is dependency whackamole. Start with the geopandas version that looks most like it'll work and go on pypi.org to find the release date and then find the subdepency on pypi and find its release around the same date

Comment: Also, at least `git blame` the project to find a coworker to strangle / ask advice from

Answer (score 1):

**I will suggest creating new conda env**

```
To install this package with conda run one of the following:
conda install -c conda-forge geopandas 
conda install -c conda-forge/label/dev geopandas 
conda install -c conda-forge/label/gcc7 geopandas 
conda install -c conda-forge/label/broken geopandas 
conda install -c conda-forge/label/rc geopandas 
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 geopandas
```

Comment: Thanks, the first issue I run into with this approach is that the current version of geopandas 0.7.0 no longer supports python 2.7. when I instead try to install an older release, the package conflicts are returned.